# Redux store not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a following `rootReducer`, which is supposed to add `userToken` inside a store:

```
const initialState = {
  userToken: ""
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "login": {
      localStorage.setItem("userToken", action.payload.token);
      return { ...state, userToken: action.payload.token };
    }
    case "logout": {
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

In my `LoginForm` component, I define `mapDispatchToProps` as follows:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    saveUserToken: token => {
      dispatch({ type: "login", payload: token });
    }
  };
};
```

And export my component using `connect()` (I pass `null` as I don't have `mapStateToProps` here):

```
export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginForm);
```

And I call it inside my component:

```
.then(data => {
  props.saveUserToken(data);
})
```

I am sure that my `rootReducer`'s `login` case gets called, as I can `console.log()` inside it and it saves `userToken` in `localStorage`.

Now in my other component, which listens on another route, I registered `mapStateToProps` like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userToken: state.userToken
  };
};

<...>

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ServerList);
```

Inside `ServerList`, which I define as follows:

```
const ServerList = ({ userToken }) => {}
```

Inside `useEffect` hook, I try to `console.log(userToken);`. What I get is empty string. What is the problem?

```
const ServerList = ({ userToken }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userToken);      
    //returns ''  
  });
  <...>
```

**EDIT**:
For the sake of testing, I implemented `mapStateToProps` inside my `LoginForm` and `console.log`'ed inside `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(props);
});
```

On form submit, `userToken` value is saved properly inside `props`, but if I reload a page, `userToken` gets set to empty string again.

Comment: Are these components connected to the same store instance? If you add that `mapStateToProps` to your `LoginForm` does the `userToken` value come through?

Comment: @dezfowler , I just implemented `mapStateToProps` in my Login form, and `console.log`'ed it inside `useEffect()`. On form submit, `userToken` is defined and value is saved correctly inside `props`. But if I reload, or visit `/login` page once again, `userToken` is empty.

Comment: You are using `action.payload.token` in reduced, but dispatching `dispatch({ type: "login", payload: token });`. So when calling `saveUserToken(token)` `token` should be object of form `token: { token: /* token is here */ }`. Is it correct?

Comment: @Kelb56 Just as an aside, your reducer should be a pure function so should not be causing side-effects like the call to `localStorage.setItem()`.  That call should be in some [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in redux store will be set back to its initial value when you reload the page. If you want to keep the data on reloading the page, you can use `redux-persist`.

Comment: Does this mean, that if I have a `react-router-dom` with couple routes, I cannot get state from store on different route?

Comment: When you change your route with ```react-router-dom```, the page is not reloaded. So you your data in redux store is not lost.

Comment: I am having hard time actually redirecting user using `history.push` in my .then() function. It changes the url and does not render my component listening on different path unless I reload page. I tried using `withRouter` HOC, but didn't help, maybe you have seen this before?

Comment: What's your react-router version? Did you try using withRouter?

Comment: Yes, I tried `withRouter`. `react-router` version is 5.0.1, `react-router-dom` version is 5.0.1 as well.

Comment: Can you post your router file? I think we have problem with it

Comment: this is my App.js https://pastebin.com/XXAqwgVC and I have defined a custom PrivateRoute component, which looks like this pastebin.com/DU5zGBCV . Sorry for pastebin, but this thread is getting really clogged

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "login": {
      localStorage.setItem("userToken", action.payload.token);
      return Object.assign({}, state, { userToken: action.payload.token })
    }
    case "logout": {
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)